# Prestashop BestSelling Product SQL Query Snytax error

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.0.9 and i want to retrieve from my database my best products between date 01/01/2015 and 31/12/2015. I wrote a query but there's an error.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.reference,
    p.id_product,
    pl.name,
    ROUND(AVG(od.product_price / o.conversion_rate), 2) as avgPriceSold,
    IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity,
    IFNULL(SUM(od.product_quantity), 0) AS totalQuantitySold,
    ROUND(IFNULL(IFNULL(SUM(od.product_quantity), 0) / (1 + LEAST(TO_DAYS('01/01/2015'), TO_DAYS(NOW())) - GREATEST(TO_DAYS('31/12/2015'), TO_DAYS(product_shop.date_add))), 0), 2) as averageQuantitySold,
    ROUND(IFNULL(SUM((od.product_price * od.product_quantity) / o.conversion_rate), 0), 2) AS totalPriceSold,
    (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(pv.counter), 0)
        FROM ps_page pa
        LEFT JOIN ps_page_viewed pv
            ON pa.id_page = pv.id_page
        LEFT JOIN ps_date_range dr
            ON pv.id_date_range = dr.id_date_range
        WHERE
            pa.id_object = p.id_product
            AND dr.time_start BETWEEN '01/01/2015 AND 31/12/2015'
            AND dr.time_end BETWEEN '01/01/2015 AND 31/12/2015'
    ) AS totalPageViewed,
    ps_product_shop.active
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl
    ON (p.id_product = pl.id_product AND pl.id_lang = '3')
LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od
    ON od.product_id = p.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_orders o
    ON od.id_order = o.id_order
WHERE
    o.valid = 1
    AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '01/01/2015 AND 31/12/2015'
GROUP BY od.product_id'
```

Here is the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') AS totalPageViewed,
>                 ps_product_shop.active
>                 FROM ps_product p
>                 LEFT ' at line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answers myself :)

That is was i need it :)

```
SELECT P.id_product as SKU, PL.`name` as Product_Name, COUNT(OD.id_order) as ordered_qty,ROUND(AVG(OD.product_price / O.conversion_rate), 2) as avgPriceSold,P.`wholesale_price`,COUNT(OD.id_order)*P.`wholesale_price` as Satis_Whosale_carpimi,COUNT(OD.id_order)*ROUND(AVG(OD.product_price / O.conversion_rate), 2) as Toplam_satis FROM ps_product P 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang PL ON P.id_product = PL.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail OD ON P.id_product = OD.product_id
LEFT JOIN ps_orders O ON O.id_order = OD.id_order
WHERE O.valid = 1 AND PL.`id_lang`=1 AND O.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY P.reference, PL.`name`
ORDER BY ordered_qty DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Amongst many errors in this query, the specific one identified concerns your use of BETWEEN.

Your should write:

```
BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '31/12/2015'
```

Instead of:

```
BETWEEN '01/01/2015 AND 31/12/2015'
```

Also you're using `stock.quantity` but there's nothing named "stock" in your query.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the logic only on syntax error.